# How to center <ion-label> inside a <ion-list-header> in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, label, ionic4

How can text in `<ion-label>` be horizontally centered within a `<ion-list-header>` element in Ionic 4?

I found the *text-center* attribute utility as shown below and documented in ionic doc, but it doesn't work.

I also tried to add `class="ion-center-text"`.

But neither test works when the `<ion-label>` is inside an `<ion-list-header>`.
But this works well if the `<ion-label>` is wrapped inside an `<ion-item>`!

```
    <ion-list-header text-center>
      <ion-label>Text not centered</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>
```

or:

```
    <ion-list-header>
      <ion-label text-center>Text still not centered</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>
```

or

```
    <ion-list-header>
      <ion-label class="ion-text-center">Text still not centered</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>
```

or

```
    <ion-list-header  class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-label>Text still not centered</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>
```

I just need a short and clean solution to center my `<ion-label>` wrapped inside an `<ion-list-header>`.

Does someone have a solution that matches the "best practices" of ionic 4 ?

---

Solution found with the help of @annaya is to change the display mode of `<ion-list-header>` either on `display:block` or better to keep `display:flex` and add `justify-content:center`. 
Like that:

```
    <ion-list-header>
      <ion-label>Text centered</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>
```

with:

```css
    list-item-header{
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

Thanks for replies, comments and english corrections ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
ion-list-header{
     display:block;
     text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ion-list-header>
      <ion-label>Text not centered</ion-label>
</ion-list-header>
```

Comment: If you want, u can also add class name

Comment: Thanks a lot, @annaya ! You put me on the good direction. But after some test, i prefer to keep the display:flex and add the justify-content: center that do the same result. With display: block; i lose the vertical center of the text. thanks.

Comment: happy to help u @cesar jacquet

Answer (score 0):

You can set left and right margin of `ion-label` to auto if you want to center it inside ion-list-header , e.g.

```
ion-label {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Also , ion-list-header comes with some default padding , make sure you set it to zero.

```
ion-list-header {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that work too ! thank you @Patwan. But i prefer the edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that ion-item and ion-label have pretty opinionated behaviors;
When they don't fit your application there is no shame in falling back to div, h1, etc;
If you just put an h1 or h2 inside your ion-list-header it should do what you want with a minimum of styling effort.

Comment: You are right, but i try to stay as close as possible with the ionic proposition and user their tools. thanks